# Angular 5 reactive forms custom control inconsistent validation state on conditionally add/remove from DOM

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Issue related to reactive forms, Angular v4.3.

**Multiselect-dropdown.component.ts**

Implemented ControlValueAccessor, Validator.
Added validate interface method as below

```
validate(ctrl: FormControl) {
  return this.selections.length > 0 ? null : {required: "no selection"} : null;
}
```

**Reactive Forms**

My form is divided into multiple sections with a let nav menu. All form is constructed in one single page and on based on menu selection, showing the part of the form using *ngIf.
I have added Multiselect-dropdown control in first section of the form.
First time form loads with first section selected by default.

All works good till here.

Now i have clicked the dropdown but not selected any item which leave the dropdown empty. Here since i touched the control, it shows required validation error. Now leaving the error, i switch to another section and come back to the first section. Now it still shows the required validation error which is correct.

Now the issue is, here if select an item from dropdown, the validate() method returns null but the required validation error doesn't go off.

After i debug, i found that since *ngIf recreate the component, the new component is not the one the FormControl created in formGroup initially.
A workaround i used is remove the FormControl from formGroup and recreate it again when switch to that section. But this is not the correct solution.

I want to understand this behaviour. I need any help that can solve or understand this issue

Here is the link
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26792 
where explained with POC and steps to reproduce

Thanks
Sankara

Comment: sounds like `[hidden]` is a better choice than `*ngIf` here

Comment: Added plunker link below
http://plnkr.co/edit/pvdUn5HejTqNbAfa87Cx

Comment: @yourFather: I have more than 400 fields that load dynamically, so that would be a performance issue. And more over i want to understand the reason behind it.